# matrix buttons 8x8

Tags: button

Hi I have 8 buttons on my Arduino uno and I want to create a matrix 8x8 and give each button a row and a column respectively it is not a keypad just 8 buttons each button have a row  and a column  ex:                   y
                                                          x(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
                                                            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                                                              .....
to compare it with other values on my visual studio c# , I can't find anything about this .
anyone can help ?

Comment: ... ... ... um... what?

Comment: sorry it's not very clear / I want to create a 8x8 matrix

Comment: An 8x8 matrix has, by its simple definition, 64 buttons. Do you have 64 buttons?

Comment: And I have 8 push buttons for each button I want to assign a row and a culomn like row[1]column[1] to push button 1

Comment: You have "8 buttons for each button" - you aren't making any sense whatsoever.

Comment: An 8x8 matrix has 64 buttons. That's what an 8x8 matrix is. The reason why you can't find an answer to your problem whilst searching is simply because you do not know what your problem is. I think you need to rewind and think about what you want to achieve, not how you think you want to go about achieving it.

Comment: @Majenko There's punctuation missing. This is how I think he means it to read: "I have 8 push buttons. For each button I want to assign a row and a column."  The question still doesn't make sense, but at least that sentence does.

Comment: I have a windows form application that have 8x8 labels each label have an x and y

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
int col;
int row;

int buttonPressed = readButtons();  // <-- You implement this!

switch (buttonPressed) {
    case 1:
       row = 7;
       col = 3;
       break;
    case 2:
       row = 1;
       col = 2;
       break;
    case 3:
       row = 0;
       col = 4;
       break;
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: something like that , when i press the button if it have the same value of x and y of the labels the label will change color , hhow can i post a pic to clarfy

Comment: The code above lets you specify an `x` and `y` (actually `row` and `col` but you can rename them) value associated with each button.  To compare them with other numbers -- use `if (row == someOtherRow)` and so on. If you want someone to plumb this into some other code you have, you'll need to post the code -- we can't guess it.

Comment: is there a way to discuss this with you by email? i'm getting a lot off errors here

Comment: Break the problem down into little pieces and get each piece working one at a time. If you're getting compiler errors, strip out all the code, and just put your little piece in, and get that working. Compare it to examples (Google...). If you can't work out a particular thing, you can post a question here (Arduino specific) or in StackOverflow (C++ questions).  If it's related to code in my answer, ask here :)

Comment: I can't add a picture here ?

Comment: i added a question please check it